# AutoCAD LISP automatizing polyline drawings

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I would like to ask a question about automatizing polyline drawing. Here I have a FUNC and I want to add more specific commands. What I mean: I want the polyline **to be assigned to a chosen layer** automatically and i also want to set the **line type** to my custom line type. Thanks for the answers.

[Here is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urxTB.png)

Comment: Please put your code (or a relevant section that you are having problems with) as text in the question, rather than linking to an image of the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the newly created polyline with the `entlast` function and change its properties with `_chprop` command.

```
(defun c:nyomvodal (/ pt lst)
  ;; create a new layer
  (command "_layer" "_new" "nyomvodal"  "_color" 3 "nyomvodal" "")

  ;; get points form user
  (while (setq pt (getpoint "\nPick point: "))
    (setq lst (cons pt lst))
  )

  (if (< 2 (length lst))
    (progn
      ;; create the polyline
      (command "_pline")
      (foreach p (reverse lst)
    (command "_non" p)
      )
      (command "")
      (command "_chprop" (entlast) "" "_layer" "nyomvodal" "_ltype" "axes" "")
    )
  )
  
  (princ)
)
```

But, typically, we save current values of the OSMODE, CLAYER and CELTYPE system variables, set new values, draw the polyline, and restore the previous values.

```
(defun c:nyomvodal (/ osmode clayer celtype)
  ;; save the current osmode, clayer and  celtype
  (setq osmode (getvar "osmode"))
  (setq clayer (getvar "clayer"))
  (setq celtype (getvar "celtype"))

  ;; create a new layer and make it current
  (command "_layer" "_make" "nyomvodal" "_color" 3 "nyomvodal" "")
  ;; set the current osmode and line type
  (setvar "osmode" 0)
  (setvar "celtype" "AXES")

  ;; use vla-catch-all-apply to avoid exiting code if user cancels
  (vl-catch-all-apply
    '(lambda (/ pt lst)
       ;; get points form user
       (while (setq pt (getpoint "\nPick point: "))
     (setq lst (cons pt lst))
       )
       (if (< 2 (length lst))
     (progn
       ;; create the polyline
       (command "_pline")
       (foreach p (reverse lst)
         (command p)
       )
       (command "")
     )
       )
     )
  )
  
  ;; restore the previous system variables values
  (setvar "osmode" osmode)
  (setvar "clayer" clayer)
  (setvar "celtype" celtype)
  (princ)
)
```